# Possible memory leak when implementing A* in C++

Tags: c++, debugging, memory-leaks, a-star

I have been programming for a little while, but I am relativly new to c++. I am trying to implement the A* algorithm and have managed to produce the code below. The implementation producces the expected result, the shortest path from point A to B in a 2D grid, but I suspect i leave behind some memory leaks.

I tested this by overloading the new and delete operators to keep track of the amount of bytes allocated on the heap and it showed that a lot of memeory never got released. However I also tested the number of nodes that never got deleted but it showed that there were that all allocated nodes also got their destructor called. Note in the code that i only call new on Node, hence my confunsion. I have much confusion about this and would be happy for an explenation.

I have tried using smart pointers, but enden up with circular refrences which were difficult to resolve.

This is also my first post on Stack Overflow so please feel free to point how I can improve my questions. Thanks in advance.

```
#include<vector>
#include<array>
#include<cmath>

int mynodes = 0;
int memory_left = 0;

void* operator new(size_t size)
{
    memory_left += size;
    return malloc(size);
}

void operator delete(void* memory, size_t size)
{
    memory_left -= size;
    free(memory);
}

struct Node{
    std::array<int, 2> position;
    Node* parent = nullptr;
    double h, g, f;

    Node(const std::array<int, 2>& pos)
        :position(pos){mynodes++;}


    ~Node(){ mynodes--; }
};


std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> find_children(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& grid, const std::array<int, 2>& pos){

    std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> children;
    children.reserve(8);

    for(int t = -1; t < 2; t++){
        for(int q = -1; q < 2; q++){
            if(t != 0 || q != 0){
                if(abs(t) == abs(q)) continue;

                std::array<int, 2> cur_pos = {pos[0]+q, pos[1]+t};
                if(cur_pos[0] >= 0 && cur_pos[0] < grid[0].size() && cur_pos[1] >= 0 && cur_pos[1] < grid.size())
                {
                    if(grid[cur_pos[1]][cur_pos[0]] == 0)
                    {
                        children.push_back(cur_pos);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return children;
}

bool search_vect(const std::vector<Node*>& set, const std::array<int, 2>& pos)
{
    for(Node* node : set)
    {
        if(node->position[0] == pos[0] && node->position[1] == pos[1]) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void releaseNodes(std::vector<Node*>& set)
{
    for(auto& node : set)
    {
        delete node;
    }
    set.clear();
}

std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> find_path(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& grid, std::array<int, 2> start, std::array<int, 2> end){

    Node* cur_node = new Node(start);
    std::vector<Node*> open_vect;
    std::vector<Node*> closed_vect;
    open_vect.push_back(cur_node);

    while(cur_node->position != end){

        double lowest_f = INFINITY;
        size_t idx = 0;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < open_vect.size(); i++)
        {
            if(open_vect[i]->f < lowest_f)
            {
                cur_node = open_vect[i];
                lowest_f = cur_node->f;
                idx = i;
            }
        }
        open_vect.erase(open_vect.begin() + idx);

        std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> children = find_children(grid, cur_node->position);
        closed_vect.push_back(cur_node);

        for(const auto& child_pos : children){
            // if(closed_vect.find(child_pos) != closed_vect.end() || open_vect.find(child_pos) != open_vect.end()) continue;
            if(search_vect(closed_vect, child_pos) || search_vect(open_vect, child_pos))
            {
                continue;
            }

            Node* new_node = new Node(child_pos);
            new_node->g = cur_node->g + 1;
            new_node->h = abs(end[0] - child_pos[0]) + abs(end[1] - child_pos[1]);
            new_node->f = new_node->g + new_node->h;
            new_node->parent = cur_node;

            // double h = sqrt(pow(end[0] - child_pos[0], 2) + pow(end[1] - child_pos[1], 2));

            open_vect.push_back(new_node);

        }
    }

    std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> path;
    while(cur_node != nullptr){
        path.push_back(cur_node->position);
        cur_node = cur_node->parent;
    }

    releaseNodes(open_vect);
    releaseNodes(closed_vect);

    return path;
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> grid( 100 , std::vector<int> (100, 0));

    {
        auto path = find_path(grid, {1, 1}, {98, 98});
    }


}
```

Comment: Welcome!  That looks like a very good first question.   Would you mind adding to the question what you have tried to do so far to understand the issue?

Comment: Heads up: `void main()` is bad. `main()` _must_ have a `int` return type. Also, this would be much simpler if you used smart pointers, like `unique_ptr`  or `shared_ptr`.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the int main() thing, the code was orginialy in a hpp file, the copy-paste just went a little too fast. I tried using smart pointers, but ended up with a lot of circular refrences wich i found hard to resolve

Comment: Get rid of the overloaded `new` and `delete`.  All they will do is confuse the problem even more.

Comment: The best way to avoid memory leaks is to make it logically impossible for them to happen. Not `new`ing and `delete`ing anything makes it logically impossible to leak anything. C++ containers are perfectly adequate for storing and accessing dynamically-allocated objects in a variety of ways, and the C++ containers will do all the work of making sure memory gets properly deleted. Why do you insist on going through the headache of managing memory yourself when C++ containers will be more than happy to do it for you? You will find `new` and `delete` to be very rare in modern C++ code.

Comment: Wouldnt circular smart pointer refrences lead to memory leaks? I used new and delete to better understand when nodes were allocated/deallocated, the goal is to get rid of them but for now I use them to make allocations more apperent

Comment: Unrelated: Your `void operator delete(void* memory, size_t size)` should be `void operator delete(void* memory, size_t size) noexcept` (to not generate warnings)

Comment: The canonical way for searching memory leaks is using the Address Sanitizer which can be activated i.e. in gcc using ```-fsanitize=address```. This will tell you if you have a leak and probably even the faulty line of your code if you compile in debug mode. It will do all the instrumentation for you, so you can get rid of your new/delete implementations.

Comment: The trick with smart pointers is **not** to use them everywhere. It is totally fine to use normal pointers, as long as the owner (e.g. a function or class; the owner can change during execution) of the resource has a smart pointer pointing to it. So for example the pointers to parent nodes should not be smart pointers, as each node doesn't "own" it's parent node. Differently phrased the parent node should not die, when it's kids die.

Comment: Generally one would just not have a vector of pointers to nodes, but a vector of nodes. There can be performance problems with that, but they can be fixed without resorting to explicit pointers via move semantics, in-place construction and keeping in mind that RVO (Return Value Optimization) exists.

Comment: Confirm that your `operator delete` is actually called. Sized delete is new with C++14.

Comment: `operator delete` does get called. I am compiling with gcc C++17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the minimal/easy way of getting rid of any explicit new/delete:

```cpp
#include<vector>
#include<array>
#include<cmath>

struct Node{
    std::array<int, 2> position;
    Node* parent = nullptr;
    double h{0.};
    double g{0.};
    double f{0.};
    Node(const std::array<int, 2>& pos)
        : position(pos) {}
};


std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> find_children(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& grid, const std::array<int, 2>& pos){

    std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> children;
    children.reserve(8);

    for(int t = -1; t < 2; t++){
        for(int q = -1; q < 2; q++){
            if(t != 0 || q != 0){
                if(abs(t) == abs(q)) continue;

                std::array<int, 2> cur_pos = {pos[0]+q, pos[1]+t};
                if(cur_pos[0] >= 0 && cur_pos[0] < grid[0].size() && cur_pos[1] >= 0 && cur_pos[1] < grid.size())
                {
                    if(grid[cur_pos[1]][cur_pos[0]] == 0)
                    {
                        children.push_back(cur_pos);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return children;
}

bool search_vect(const std::vector<Node*>& set, const std::array<int, 2>& pos)
{
    for(Node* node : set)
    {
        if(node->position[0] == pos[0] && node->position[1] == pos[1]) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> find_path(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& grid, std::array<int, 2> start, std::array<int, 2> end){

    std::vector<Node> nodes{};
    nodes.emplace_back(start);
    Node* cur_node = &nodes.back();
    std::vector<Node*> open_vect;
    std::vector<Node*> closed_vect;
    open_vect.push_back(cur_node);

    while(cur_node->position != end){

        double lowest_f = INFINITY;
        size_t idx = 0;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < open_vect.size(); i++)
        {
            if(open_vect[i]->f < lowest_f)
            {
                cur_node = open_vect[i];
                lowest_f = cur_node->f;
                idx = i;
            }
        }
        open_vect.erase(open_vect.begin() + idx);

        std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> children = find_children(grid, cur_node->position);
        closed_vect.push_back(cur_node);

        for(const auto& child_pos : children){
            // if(closed_vect.find(child_pos) != closed_vect.end() || open_vect.find(child_pos) != open_vect.end()) continue;
            if(search_vect(closed_vect, child_pos) || search_vect(open_vect, child_pos))
            {
                continue;
            }
            nodes.emplace_back(child_pos);
            Node* new_node = &nodes.back();
            new_node->g = cur_node->g + 1;
            new_node->h = abs(end[0] - child_pos[0]) + abs(end[1] - child_pos[1]);
            new_node->f = new_node->g + new_node->h;
            new_node->parent = cur_node;

            // double h = sqrt(pow(end[0] - child_pos[0], 2) + pow(end[1] - child_pos[1], 2));

            open_vect.push_back(new_node);

        }
    }

    std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> path;
    while(cur_node != nullptr){
        path.push_back(cur_node->position);
        cur_node = cur_node->parent;
    }

    return path;
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> grid( 100 , std::vector<int> (100, 0));

    {
        auto path = find_path(grid, {1, 1}, {98, 98});
    }


}
```

This is not perfect, but it easily demonstrates how easy it is to not cause any potential memory leaks. Instead of replacing the vectors of pointers with vectors of nodes, I just added an additional vector of nodes (the owner). Now the pointers are non-owning and nothing weird should happen anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your  answer. When i run the code above I get a seg-fault. After som debugging, the problem seems to occur when the the end position in reached. I also seems to be a problem with push_back on a `vector of type std::vector<std::array<int, 2>>`. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I fixed the seg-fault problem by giving the h, g and f values of the nodes a default value of 0

Comment: I don't see any problem when using ```push_back``` on ```std::vector<std::array<int, 2> >``` in some minimal example code. What exactly is that problem you are observing?

Comment: I was getting a seg-fault when running the code. There was not any problem with the push_back, my debugger just happend to include some information with `push_back` which I misinterpered. I fixed the problem by switching from `new/delete` to `uniqe_ptr`and giving the variables in the Node struct a default value

Comment: Where else did you have to use ```unique_ptr``` after all your nodes are in the vector?

Comment: Could I ask just out of interest, why? Did you just need to transfer ownership of single Nodes or sth like that? Because having them in a vector should be better in terms of performance, as they are next to each other in memory. When you allocate space for each node on it's own, they might be scattered around memory. Naturally you would need to use ```std::vector```'s ```reserve()``` method to have enough memory for all the nodes from the beginning to reap such benefits.

Comment: I thought if would be better performane wise, not to have to move the nodes when the vector run out of space and instead have more of a linked list behaviour. The amount of nodes will increase quite drastically. I havent behcmarked this, but its an intersenting point you're making. I used `unique_ptr<Node>`, as opposed to your last comment

Comment: Using vectors `reserve` would be a good idea, but I have noe idea in advance, on have many nodes there will be. Therefore i thought using `unique_ptr<Node>` would be a more flexible solution

Comment: One would have to benchmark it, but I would assume that as long as you have some way to approximate the number of nodes, even if the vector will have to reallocate and copy once ore twice, it should perform better, because allocations can take some time (+ the stuff discussed before). But this is totally implementation specific.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on what an approximate would look like? Maybe distant from A to B, times 1.5 or something?

Comment: Ater reading this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Complexity I don't think that there is a general way of doing this. But maybe one could do it heuristically (find some approximations of b, d, and a factor in front)?